# Generate dates for last 3 days starting with Yesterdays date and not include sunday

Tags: c#-4.0

I am populating a datagridview with dates for the last 3 days starting
from Yesterday. Sunday date should not be included. The code below works
great but I think this can be improved with limited amount of code like writing 
just one function

How can I improve on this?

```
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var rangeList = new List<MyDates>();

                //first date
                var yesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
                string  dayoftheweek = yesterday.DayOfWeek.ToString();
                DateTime  storefirstdate;
                if (dayoftheweek == "Sunday")
                {
                    var  firstdate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2);
                    storefirstdate = firstdate;
                    rangeList.Add(new MyDates() {Dateseries = storefirstdate});             
                }
                else
                {
                    storefirstdate = yesterday;
                    rangeList.Add(new MyDates() {Dateseries = storefirstdate}); 
                }

                //second date
                var twodaysago = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2);
                string dayoftheweek2 = twodaysago.DayOfWeek.ToString();
                DateTime storeseconddate;
                if (dayoftheweek2 == "Sunday")
                {
                    var seconddate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3);
                    storeseconddate = seconddate;
                    rangeList.Add(new MyDates() {Dateseries = storeseconddate}); 
                }
                else
                {
                    storeseconddate = twodaysago;
                    rangeList.Add(new MyDates() {Dateseries = storeseconddate}); 
                }

                //Third date
                var threedaysago = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3);
                string dayoftheweek3 = threedaysago.DayOfWeek.ToString();
                DateTime storethirddate;
                if (dayoftheweek3 == "Sunday")
                {
                    var thirddate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-4);
                    storethirddate = thirddate;
                    rangeList.Add(new MyDates() {Dateseries = storethirddate});
                }
                else
                {
                    storethirddate = threedaysago;
                    rangeList.Add(new MyDates() {Dateseries = storethirddate});
                }

                dataGridView1.DataSource = rangeList.OrderByDescending(j=>j.Dateseries).ToList();           

            }


             public class MyDates
            {       
                public DateTime  Dateseries { get; set; }
            }
```

The result should look like this  if processed today- Tuesday-11/08/2016,Monday -11/07/2016,Saturday - 11/05/2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can do it using linq.
The integer array is not exactelly beautiful, perhaps someone can sugest a more elegant solution for that.

```
IEnumerable<MyDates> rangeList = new [] {1, 2, 3, 4}.Select(n => DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(n))) // Transforming the integer (kind of index of days) array into dates.
    .Where(n => n.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday).Take(3) // Removing the Sunday and taking 3 days only.
    .Select(n => new MyDates() { Dateseries = n }); // Converting the date in your MyDates structure.
```

Comment: Thanks. At least it is way shorter than my code. It works. The only thing is that it returns the time in this format too. 11/8/2016 2.55pm

Comment: On the UI? This code gives you the date, you can choose how to show this date to your UI as you want. If you want more control on that you can override the `ToString()` method on your MyDate to return something like this `$"{Dateseries.DayOfWeek} - {Dateseries.ToString("d")}"`.